# Missing current value for "B1" (LTspice)

Tags: ltspice, solar-cell

I've been trying to make an LTspice solar panel model based on this video:
https://youtu.be/ox0UtYe4owI (2:45). This is the circuit that I got:

[image]

When I try to run a simulation I get an error:

"Error on line 2 : i§b1 0 n001 i=v(illu)/(1000*iph)
Unknown parameter "i"
Fatal Error: Missing current value for "B1" "

If I add curly braces (i={v(illu)/(1000 * iph)}) I get:

" Questionable use of curly braces in "i§b1 0 n001 i={v(illu)/(1000*iph)}"
Error: undefined symbol in: "v/(1000*iph)"
Error on line 2 : i§b1 0 n001 i=(v(illu)/(1000*iph))
Unknown parameter "i"
Fatal Error: Missing current value for "B1" "

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like "B1" is set to have a prefix of "I", making it an I source and not a B source. I sources cannot use the "I=whatever" syntax.

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: Turn B1 into an actual B source by changing its prefix to B.

Comment: Or use the correct symbol in the first place which is `bi`. Looks like you used `current` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a "Voltage dependent current source"
"g" in the component list.

[image]